# Error activating IRepository{MyModel}

Tags: ninject

Situation:

Interfaces:

```
IRepository<T>
IMyModelRepository : IRepository<MyModel>
```

Classes:

```
Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
MyModelRepository : Repository<MyModel>, IMyModelRepository
```

Bindings:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(Namespace.IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Namespace.Repository<>)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(Namespace.IRepositoryInternal<>)).To(typeof(Namespace.Repository<>)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(Namespace.IMyModelRepository)).To(typeof(NameSpace.MyModelRepository)).InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind(scanner => scanner
                .FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(Namespace.SomeService))
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .Excluding<Namespace.MyModelRepository>()
                .BindDefaultInterfaces()
                .Configure(binding => binding.InRequestScope()));
```

Injection:

```
readonly IRepository<MyModel> _MyModelRepository; //this is the property, injection is constructor injection
```

Problem:

Error activating IRepository{WarningModel}
More than one matching bindings are available.
Activation path:
 5) Injection of dependency IRepository{MyModel} into parameter MyModelRepository of constructor of type AnotherService

What am i missing? where is the multiple binding?

If this info is not enough, i can provide extra info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `.BindDefaultInterfaces()`. It should have been `.BindDefaultInterface()`.